# Azure Policy evaluation fails when parameter is string

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I'm struggling with a policy which should allow only certain values for tags.
Here is the code

```
{
"mode": "Indexed",
"policyRule": {
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
      },
      {
        "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
        "notIn": "[parameters('listOfAllowedValues')]"
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deny"
  }
},
"parameters": {
  "tagName": {
    "type": "String",
    "metadata": {
      "displayName": "Tag Name",
      "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
    }
  },
  "listOfAllowedValues": {
    "type": "Array",
    "metadata": {
      "displayName": "Allowed values",
      "description": "The list of values which tag can have."
    }
  }
}
```

}

I put this array for assigments: ["Not Appliable","1","2","3","4"]
Policy evaluation works perfectly fine for numbers, but when I put tag value to be Not applicable policy always denies creation of VM.
Not sure what's wrong with it..Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your policy definition, for the parameter `listOfAllowedValues` you are passing the allowed values as **Notappliable** and while creating the virtual machine you are passing the tag value as **NotApplicable** since there is spelling mistake that is the reason your policy valuation is getting failed.

I have test the above policy in my local and it working as expected from my end.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but I did a typo while putting this questions, so I'm sure there is the same value in tag and assigment.

Comment: This is error I get: {
                  "result": "True",
                  "expressionKind": "Value",
                  "expression": "[string(field(concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')))]",
                  "expressionValue": "Not Applicable",
                  "targetValue": [
                    "Not Applicable",
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4"
                  ],
                  "operator": "NotIn"
                }
              ],
              "reason": "Tag should be 1-4"
            },

Comment: @iuriiIashchenko could you please update the question with the error message and the inputs you are passing and also what the expected result is as well.